# Why does replacing outliers with np.nan removes all of my non-zero data in that column?

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I am trying to replace outliers with .nan values (not the whole column), so that I can fill in all .nan values with the median. I have tried two approaches so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def outlier_thresholds(dataframe, col_name, low_q = 0.05, up_q= 0.95):
    q1, q3 = np.nanpercentile(dataframe[col_name], [low_q, up_q])
    iqr = q3 - q1
    lower_thres = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)
    upper_thres = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
    return lower_thres, upper_thres

def check_outlier(dataframe, col_name):
    lower_thres, upper_thres = outlier_thresholds(dataframe, col_name)
    if dataframe[(dataframe[col_name] > upper_thres) | 
                 (dataframe[col_name] < lower_thres)].any(axis=None):
        return True
    return False

outlier_list = []
for col in num_list:
    if check_outlier(df, col):
        outlier_list.append(col)

def remove_outlier(dataframe, col_name):
    lower_thres, upper_thres = outlier_thresholds(dataframe, col_name)
    df_without = dataframe[~((dataframe[col_name] < lower_thres) | (dataframe[col_name] > upper_thres))]
    return df_without

for col in outlier_list:
    new_df = remove_outlier(df, col)
```

**remove_outlier** function returns a new dataset where outliers are removed. I can see from the graph that there are still values inside the column. However, I did not write this code and mine is not working, and I would like to understand why.

[boxplot of BsmtFinSF2 variable after the first given code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sjsk.png)

**drop_outliers** function seems to replace all of the data in that column with nan values, therefore I have an empty graph/column since all of the data remaining has either nan or 0 as a value.

```
def drop_outliers(dataframe, col_name):
    lower_thres, upper_thres = outlier_thresholds(dataframe, col_name)
    dataframe.loc[(dataframe[col_name] < lower_thres) | (dataframe[col_name] > upper_thres), dataframe[col_name]] = np.nan

for col in outlier_list:
    drop_outliers(df, col)
```

[boxplot of BsmtFinSF2 variable after the second given code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbZIM.png)

I have checked for duplicates about this issue, therefore I am aware I can use other paths to approach this problem but I still have not figured out the problem with my code. Could I get some assistance?

**Edit:** Sample data:

```
sample_df = {0: 0.0,
 1: 0.0,
 2: 0.0,
 3: 0.0,
 4: 0.0,
 5: 0.0,
 6: 0.0,
 7: 32.0,
 8: 0.0,
 9: 0.0,
 10: 0.0,
 11: 0.0,
 12: 0.0,
 13: 0.0,
 14: 0.0,
 15: 0.0,
 16: 0.0,
 17: 0.0,
 18: 0.0,
 19: 0.0,
 20: 0.0,
 21: 0.0,
 22: 0.0,
 23: 0.0,
 24: 668.0,
 25: 0.0,
 26: 486.0,
 27: 0.0,
 28: 0.0,
 29: 0.0}
```

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using quantiles where NumPy expects a percentile.

The NumPy docs for [`np.nanpercentile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html) say this:

> q: array_like of float
>
> Percentile or sequence of percentiles to compute, which must be between 0 and 100 inclusive.

If you use the values  0.05 and 0.95, then NumPy computes the 0.05% and 0.95% percentiles. Since more than 1% of your values are zero, this means that q1 and q3 are zero. Then, that means that your IQR is also zero.

You could fix this either by using `low_q = 5, up_q= 95` or by using `np.nanquantile()`, which uses quantiles between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the late answer. I have tried changing my code to the following: ```low_q = 5, up_q = 95``` but I still have some values that looks like [this before the removal of outliers](https://imgur.com/a/NKkACYa) and looks like [this after the removal of outliers](https://imgur.com/a/y1pFTb1). Since it looks like an empty graph after the removal of outliers, does it not mean that it is an empty set?

Comment: Don't know. Could be the empty set, could be that all remaining values are zero. Under the definition you're using, if more than 95% of values are zero, then all non-zero values are outliers. I world suggest printing it out to tell the difference.